# How to Get Most Viewed Product Collection in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection, reports, view

how to get the most viewed product collection in your Magento 2 store?

I try with multiple codes but unfortunately, I am not getting any solution.

I try to create a MostViewedProducts.php file in the /Productslider/Block/ folder & paste the code to get the most viewed product collection in the block. but, not working.

Comment: share the code what you are doing and what not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Blockname extends Template
{
   protected $_productsFactory;
   protected $_storeManager;    

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addViewsCount()
                       ->setStoreId($currentStoreId)
                       ->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId);

    return $collection->getItems();
}
}



<?php
$collection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($collection as $_product) {
echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

Add above colllection in the phtml file assigned to block.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create one block file on our custom extension add MostViewedProducts.php in following path
**app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\MostViewedProducts.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class MostViewedProducts extends Template
{
    protected $_productsFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;   

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
   
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
                           ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                           ->addViewsCount()
                           ->setStoreId($currentStoreId)
                           ->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId);

        return $collection->getItems();
    }
}
```

2.Then create list.phtml file on following path
**app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\list.phtml.**

```
<?php
$collection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($collection as $_product) {
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

3.Then flush cache and test result.